# Creative way to find this area

Tags: integration, geometry, analytic-geometry

Let's say We have a circle with center at $(0,0)$ with radius $r$
and we have the line $y=a$ where $0 \leq a \leq r$.

the question is what is the area that between the circle and the line $y=a$(the area that above the line).

illustration for $r=5$ and $a=4$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D25+and+y%3D4

We will end with the area as a function of $a$. So far I have tried to do integration to get the area ... it is not pretty at all.

Comment: Your illustration suggests you want $y=a$ and not $y=a\cdot r$ as your line...

Comment: right. I changed it and forgot to update.

Comment: can you tell us whats going wrong

Comment: @Ilaya, nothing. just my feeling that something so elementary should look better than this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+%28%2825-x%5E2%29%5E0.5%29+-+4+between++0+and+%289-y%5E2%29%5E0.5

Comment: When I saw the title, I thought it could refer to **really** creative ways. Like painting the respective area on 80g/m² paper, cutting it out and determining its area via its weight. But sure, integration will also do the job.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: The area is the difference between the areas of a sector of the circle and a triangle.

Comment: Thanks. on a second look, the integration was not so ugly as it first seem.. :).

Answer (score 2):

Using, geometry we have the equation of the circle centered at the origin as:
$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$
Now, substitute $y=a$ in the above equation
$$x^2+a^2=r^2 \implies x=\pm \sqrt{r^2-a^2}$$
Now, join the points of intersection $(\sqrt{r^2-a^2}, a),\,(-\sqrt{r^2-a^2}, a)$ to the origin, to get a sector with radius $r$ and an isosceles triangle with sides $r,\,r,\,2\sqrt{r^2-a^2}$

The aperture angle $\alpha$ of the sector is calculated as
$$\alpha=2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{r}\right)$$ 
Now, the area between the circle and the line is 
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2}\cdot\alpha r^2-\frac{1}{2}(a)(2\sqrt{r^2-a^2})\\
=\:&\frac{1}{2}\left(2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{r}\right)\right)r^2-\frac{1}{2}a\left(2\sqrt{r^2-a^2}\right)\\
=\:&r^2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{r}\right)-a\sqrt{r^2-a^2}
\end{align}
$$

Where, $0\leq a\leq r$

Hence, as you mentioned for $r=5,\,a=4$. substituting these values in the expression, we get the area:
$$
\begin{align}
&5^2\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)-4\sqrt{5^2-4^2}\\
=\:&25\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)-12\\
\approx\:&4.08752772 \space \text{unit}^2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I've edited the formatting of your math, please check that I didn't change the intent of your post.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the right triangle $(0,0), (0,a), (r \cos(\arcsin(\frac ar)),a)$ and the sector $(r \cos(\arcsin \frac ar), a), (0,r)$. Their difference in area is half the area you describe.

The area of the triangle is $\frac12 ar \cos(\arcsin \frac ar)$ and the area of the sector is $\frac{\frac\pi2-\arcsin \frac ar}2 r^2$

Answer (score 0):

Draw a radius from the origin to the point on the circle where the line $y=a$ intersects it.  Now you have the area of a sector plus the area of a right-angled triangle.  Easy.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand what arcsin is so I have written this,

Take the angle subtended by the line at the centre of the circle. Can be done by dividing triangles into 2 halves which will be right triangles. So, $\tan\theta=\frac{upper side}{a}$
Then we can take area of the sector

> Which is $\frac1{2\pi}\theta \pi r^2$

Then take the area of the triangle. $2.(A_{sector}-A_{triangle})$ will give the answer.

Comment: $\arcsin$ and $\arccos$ are the unambiguous ways to write $\sin^{-1}$ and $\cos^{-1}$.

Comment: @kristoffer oh was that it. The inverse functions! Somebody should standardize things.! Thanks,

Comment: Yeah, the best standard to use is IMO $\arcsin$ since $\sin^{-1}(x)\ne\frac1{\sin x}$, but $\sin^2(x)=(\sin x)^2$

Comment: @kristoffer yeah it was rather confusing in the start